# subset and calculate mean between two rows in a column

Tags: r

I want to subset a data by date and calculate the mean between two rows in the given data. My data looks like;

```
Station Date    Month  Day Year    MaxTemp MinTemp MaxDewPoint MinDewPoint
ORD     1/1/1948    1   1   1948    35.6    26.6    34.16         -27.4
ORD     1/2/1948    1   2   1948    -2      -16     -16.96       -27.04
ORD     1/3/1948    1   3   1948    -4      -26     -12            -26
ORD     1/4/1948    1   4   1948    -5      -26     -15             -26
ORD     1/5/1948    1   5   1948    8       -25     3               -20
ORD     1/6/1948    1   6   1948    -11     -25     -24            -25
ORD     1/7/1948    1   7   1948    1       -23     -20            -23
ORD     1/8/1948    1   8   1948    1       -22     -9              -20
ORD     1/9/1948    1   9   1948    NaN     -22     -5             -22
ORD     1/10/1948   1   10  1948    10      NaN     -2              -22
ORD     1/11/1948   1   11  1948    -11     -21    -23              -21
ORD     1/12/1948   1   12  1948    3       -12     -7.96        -20.92
ORD     1/13/1948   1   13  1948    6.98    -7.6    -7.6         -20.2
ORD     1/14/1948   1   14  1948    3.92    -9.4    -11.2        -20
ORD     1/15/1948   1   15  1948    6        -7    -5.98         -20
ORD     1/16/1948   1   16  1948    3       -11     -7.96       -20.02
```

I have this data all the way to 2018, but has lots of missing values after 2010, so i want to subset it and calculate the mean between the two MaxDewPoint and MinDewPoint to Mean like below;

```
Station Date    Month  Day Year    MaxTemp MinTemp MaxDewPoint MinDewPoint Mean
ORD     1/1/1948    1   1   1948    35.6    26.6    34.16         -27.4    3.3
ORD     1/2/1948    1   2   1948    -2      -16     -16.96       -27.04    -22
ORD     1/3/1948    1   3   1948    -4      -26     -12            -26     -19
ORD     1/4/1948    1   4   1948    -5      -26     -15             -26   -20.5
ORD     1/5/1948    1   5   1948    8       -25     3               -20    8.5
```

Comment: What issues have you run into? What have you tried?

Comment: `df1$Mean <- rowMeans(df1[, c("MaxDewPoint", "MinDewPoint")], na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Snorm, i tried somewhat similar to Rui Barradas which will calculate the mean from 1948 to 2018. But i want to calculate only up to December of 2009.

Comment: If all you need is to filter the table, then would it work to just run `df = df[df$Year <= 2009,]` before (or after) you do the row calculations?